# Configuring Kubeflow Pipelines to run Docker Images

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubeflow-pipelines

I am new to Kubeflow and I am currently trying to schedule two Docker images that are stored in my GitLab registry. Despite trying to figure it out, I'm still unable to understand how to pull these images and run them using Kubeflow.

Any code examples, documentation links, or best practice recommendations would be extremely helpful.